# проблема подключении прокси telethon python

Tags: python, proxy, telethon

Здраствуйте у меня проблема .

Я подключаюсь к прокси через windows , после захожу в тг акаунт подключаю ещё там прокси ,после захожу на сайт 2ip.ru и мне показывает что я подключён к прокси и всё хорошо .

но когда я через бота telethon делаю вход в аккаунт то мне в тг приселает что в ваш акаунт был сделан вход через такой ip - (мой айпи)

у меня вопрос если я подключён к прокси почему тогда у меня тлеграм детектит мой реальный ip ?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import socks

client = TelegramClient(phone , api_id , api_hash , proxy=(socks.HTTP,proxy_ip , proxy_port,proxy_login , proxy_password))
client.start()

print(client.get_me())
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь вот этот фрагмент кода:

```
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())
```

Этот костыль подробнее был рассмотрен здесь - [ссылка](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1337#issuecomment)